# The output textlines of the text .txt document to a TextBlock

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7

Page of the application with the TextBlock and Button, also involved .txt document with the text (Proposals, each proposal on the same line, only about 100 lines). When you click on a Button sentence (the first textline of the document) is displayed in the TextBlock:

```
public string GetQ()
    {
        string pathFile = "Q.txt";
        Uri uri = new Uri(pathFile, UriKind.Relative); 
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream))
        {
            string wordline = sr.ReadLine();
            return wordline;
        }

    }
```

How do I make the next time you press the Button, appeared the next line of the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but you could just store the file in a string array and then access what you need out of there without reopening the file constantly to read each line.

```
var qFile = new List<string>();

public string GetQ()
{
    string pathFile = "Q.txt";
    Uri uri = new Uri(pathFile, UriKind.Relative); 
    StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream))
    {
        string line = "";
        while ((line != null)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine());
            if (line != null)
                qFile.Add(line);  // Add to list
    }
}
```

Now you can just load `qFile[0]` to `qFile[qFile.Count - 1]`.

Comment: Could you explain a little more detail about load qFile[0] to qFile[qFile.Count - 1]? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are after can be done easily by File.ReadLines as shown in my quick few lines of code (no unit test done it)

```
    private static int LineNumber = 0;
    private List<string> textLines = new List<string>();

    public string GetTextLine()
    {
        const string pathFile = @"C:\test\Q.txt";

        if (textLines.Count == 0)
        {
            textLines = File.ReadLines(pathFile).ToList();
        }

        if (LineNumber < (textLines.Count - 1))
        {
            return textLines[LineNumber++];
        }

        return textLines[LineNumber];
    }
```

Hope it helps you good luck...

Comment: Error: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLines'